# How to automatically pass a command after ssh login to a linux server

Tags: linux, ssh

I use a tool called winsshterm... its basically a wrapper for Putty. I would like to know how to pass a command as soon as I Ssh to a linux server. my immediate home directory is: /home/myusername

the command I want to execute is:

mkdir .ssh ; curl https://download_this_file.com:9090/ssh/pubkey > .ssh/authorized_keys ; chmod 400 .ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: There's an environment variable called `SSH_CONNECTION`. I think you could just add a script the normal way you would in `~/.bashrc` and test against the aforementioned variable

Comment: If you used OpenSSH (via Cygwin or the native Windows version) you simply execute the command at the end of the line, something like ssh user@my.host.com "mkdir .ssh ; curl https://download_this_file.com:9090/ssh/pubkey > .ssh/authorized_keys ; chmod 400 .ssh/authorized_keys"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that in WinSSHTerm:

1. Create a file e.g `myscript` and put your commands into it. The command`bash --login` at the end of the line will prevent closing the session:

   `mkdir .ssh ; curl https://download_this_file.com:9090/ssh/pubkey > .ssh/authorized_keys ; chmod 400 .ssh/authorized_keys ; bash --login`
2. In WinSSHTerm, enter following into the field `Cmd-line Args` of the connection's config. After the flag `-m` enter the path to your script, e.g.:

   `-t -m "C:\Users\pat\Documents\WinSSHTerm\myscript"`
3. Now open the connection and the commands will be executed on the remote server